# Z-index and flyout buttons on a project inside of relative container

Tags: html, css, position, z-index, svg-edit

I am implementing SVG-edit into my website. It is designed to be full screen, but I have shrunk it to fit on my page, and changed some CSS to make this work, most importantly, putting it inside of this div.

```
#master_editor_container {
    position: relative;
    height: 600px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #ABCDEF;
}
```

I have a button, that when clicked, should cause flyout buttons to have it's display: none removed and appear on the screen next to the button that was clicked to activate them. The elements are on the HTML document. I have used inspect element after activating them to be sure there is no display: none applied. I have applied the highest z-element to the flyout buttons and their container. I have applied all the position relative, absolute, and fixed in several combinations to the button and it's containers. I have even used opacity: 0.9 to try to push the flyout buttons up.When I remove "position: relative", the flyout buttons are visible, but of course, svg-edit overflows the box I'm trying to contain it in.

Here is all the directly relevant CSS, however there are several moving parts. For the full HTML, [see this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/mHiriD2y). For the full CSS, [see this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/MATbZeyZ). To see an example of what it should look like, see the original at [the latest stable version](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/stable/editor/svg-editor.html)

**This is the div containing the button to activate the flyout**

```
#tools_left {
    position: absolute;
    border-right: none;
    width: 32px;
    top: 40px;
    left: 1px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    background: #D0D0D0; /* Needed so flyout icons don't appear on the left */
    z-index: 4;
}
```

**This is CSS applied directly to the flyout button container**

```
.tools_flyout {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 400px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**This is CSS applied directly to the flyout buttons themselves**

```
.tools_flyout .tool_button {
    float: left;
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-right: 1px solid #808080;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
}
```

**According to comments, this is necessary to keep the flyouts sized properly**

```
.tools_flyout .tool_button,
.tools_flyout .tool_flyout {
    padding: 2px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Given what I'm trying to achieve and what I've tried, what might be causing these buttons not to display?

Another acceptable answer would be to suggest a way to keep svg-edit project inside of a div without using a container with "position:relative".

Comment: How do you calculate "top" and "left" position of absolute positioned elements (.tools_flyout) after click? might you need initial positions e.g. top:100px;left:0; before animatiing?

Comment: I have now tried that on each of my absolute positioned elements, included .tool_flyout. No luck.

Comment: also try giving child elements greater z-index instead of setting 9999 for all elements.

Comment: No luck. It's the only element I have 9999 set to. I've tried setting it lower and higher in all sorts of combinations. Because of your suggestion, I gave that another go. I've been wrestling with this issue for many a few weeks now. I'm suspecting it's something subtle or obvious, but have been working on it too long to be in the right mindset to spot it.